# Helm - overwrite specific values from values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm using Helm and for [`nginx-ingress`](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress) I need to add some annotations.

Inside the chart's [`values.yaml`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/values.yaml) file, the `podAnnotations` is empty (`{}`).

The question I have is: what is the right way to add these annotations?

The annotations are a child of `controller` which is the root element of the `values.yaml`

```
controller:
  ...
  podAnnotations:
    ...
```

Now, I get the feeling that I have to copy the whole `values.yaml` file into  my `custom-values.yaml` in which I added the annotations.

```
$> heml install -f ./custom-values.yaml stable/nginx-ingress
```

But if I copy the whole values file I get the feeling that I can run into trouble if `stable/nginx-ingress` changes values inside `values.yaml` over time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have to copy all values as you can use your own and override only the values you need

> The values.yaml file is also important to templates. This file contains the default values for a chart. These values may be overridden by users during helm install or helm upgrade

See https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/

Thus just add the annotations to `custom-values.yaml` - plus other default values you want to change - and then run

```
helm install -f ./custom-values.yaml stable/nginx-ingress
```

Here an example of my `custom-values.yaml`

```
controller:
  service:
    annotations: 
       field.cattle.io/projectId: c-xxxxx:p-xxxxx
```

and the important part of the result:

```
...
# Source: nginx-ingress/templates/controller-service.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    field.cattle.io/projectId: "c-xxxxx:p-xxxxx"
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.20.0
    component: "controller"
    heritage: Tiller
    release: release-name
  name: release-name-nginx-ingress-controller
...
```